# Bot Get Channel Data

Tags: javascript, c#, botframework, bots, direct-line-botframework

Team,
I have developed a bot using bot framework SDK4.
I am using Directline channel to communicate with my bot.
My requirement is based on channeldata on 'requestWelcomeDialog' message I have to show welcome message.

Code from my bot client:

```
BotChat.App({
    botConnection: botConnection,
    user: userOption,
    bot: { id: model.botId, name: model.botName },
    resize: 'window',
    speechOptions: speechOptions,
    locale: 'en',
    sendTypingIndicator: true,
}, document.getElementById('BotChatElement'));
PostBotConfiguration();
botConnection
    .postActivity({
        from: user,
        name: 'requestWelcomeDialog',
        type: 'event',
        value: { 'BotType': 'abcd' }
    })
    .subscribe(function (id) {
        setWCScreenChatPosition();
        model.botRender = true;
        console.log('"trigger requestWelcomeDialog" sent');
    });
```

In the above code i am sending BotType as 'abcd'. 
I am trying to read this value from my bot.

My code in bot.

```
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Utility util = new Utility();
    try
    {
        foreach (var member in membersAdded)
        {
            if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                BotChannelData cdata = new BotChannelData();
                turnContext.Activity.TryGetChannelData(out cdata);
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

In this I am always getting null reference exception.

May I know what I am missing in this?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes Kyle I am still facing same issue.:-(

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I will update you shortly.

Comment: Would you consider upvoting and accepting my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you're using Bot Chat. Bot Chat is Web Chat v3 and it's deprecated. You should be using Web Chat v4 according to the instructions in [the repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat).

The second problem is that you're trying to respond to a custom event using `OnMembersAddedAsync` which is only triggered by conversation update activities. You can see how to send and respond to welcome events by following the instructions in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2120#issuecomment-516056614) and [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event). The C# equivalent would look like this:

```
if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "webchat/join")
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Back Channel Welcome Message!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Direct Line channel, you should use Web Chat v4. Because Web Chat v3 is now deprecated.
You could get the sending welcome message code from [this official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event#completed-code).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Send welcome event</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { margin: 0 }

      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat"></div>
    <script>
      (async function () {

        const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
        const { token } = await res.json();

       const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
         if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
           dispatch({
             type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
             payload: {
               name: 'webchat/join',
               value: { language: window.navigator.language }
             }
           });
         }
         return next(action);
       });

        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
          directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
        store
        }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

        document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
      })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```